# Why do I get a Infinite Loop (Prolog)

Tags: prolog, infinite-loop

I am just starting to learn Prolog and I played around with it. Now I got to a point where I´m stuck. The program i wrote gets into an infinite loop when I ask for

```
?- q(b).
```

and I don´t understand why it does that. It would be nice if someone could explain it to me.

```
p(a).    
p(b).
q(Y) :- r(X), r(Y).    
r(X) :- r(f(X)).    
r(a) :- p(c).    
r(a) :- p(a).    
r(b) :- p(b).
```

Comment: A hint: it is for the same reason that `r(something_completely_different)` does not terminate.

Comment: In general, try to think about how Prolog derives a fact: it takes the current goal (e.g. `r(something)` and goes through the rules from top to bottom to find a rule head that unifies with it. Then it tries to derive each of the goals in the body of that rule from left to right. Prolog will only attempt to derive the second goal of the body, when it has derived the first one - this is also called depth first search.

Comment: Ok. So that means the program starts with "q(Y) :- r(X), r(Y). ". After that it wants to check "r(X)" and goes to "r(X) :- r(f(X)).". There it tries to check "r(f(x))." and it loops in "r(X) :- r(f(X)).". Do i understand that correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what happens :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the comment, the loop is caused by `r/1`. To show why, yust type `?- trace, q(b).` Look at the trace (ignore by now the singleton warning):

```
 Call:q(b)
 Call:r(_4244)
 Call:r(f(_4162))
 Call:r(f(f(_4162)))
 Call:r(f(f(f(_4162))))
 Call:r(f(f(f(f(_4162)))))
 Call:r(f(f(f(f(f(_4162))))))
 Call:r(f(f(f(f(f(f(_4162)))))))
 Call:r(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(_4162))))))))
```

Now you can see that it try to derives `r/1` entering a loop. You can see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49954314/swi-prolog-understanding-infinite-loops) to have a more in depth explaination.

Notice that in prolog, the order of the clauses matters. Just try to put the line `r(X) :- r(f(X)).` to the bottom of your program. Now try `?- q(b).` On the first answer you get `true` because prolog unifies `X` with `a` and `Y` with `b` before entering in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to identify reasons for non-termination is to reduce the number of inferences your program will execute by adding goals **`false`** into your program:

```
q(Y) :- r(X), false, r(Y).

r(X) :- r(f(X)), false.
r(a) :- false, p(c).
r(a) :- false, p(a).
r(b) :- false, p(b).

?- q(Y).
   loops.
```

Since this program is still looping, you will need to modify something in the visible part.  Note how many things have been removed entirely! No matter how `p/1` is defined, this problem will persist.

If you look at `q/1` closely, you see one of the problems:

```
q(Y) :- r(X), false, r(Y).
```

The variable `Y` is not used in the visible part at all.  The `X` appears just once.  Thus, `r(X)` will be the most general query possible and thus it will have the worst termination property possible (that depends on the definition of `r/1`, indeed). In any case, the argument of `q/1` has no influence on termination!

There is another property to conclude: The order of clauses does not have any influence on the termination property! You can see this easily: No matter where the clauses that have been removed entirely with **`false`** appear, they can be removed.

For more, see [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice).